# Check if SKU exists

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, import, sku

I'm logging a bunch of stuff in our database. Is there a quick and easy way to check if a SKU exists or not?  This way I can remove anything malformed from our import process.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$sku = 'sku here';
$id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
if (false !== $id) {
   //sku exists
}
else {
   //sku does not exist
}
```

Comment: Really? Yoda conditions?

Comment: Wrong with it what is? In my defense it was just `if($id)` when I wrote it.

Comment: Well then, my apologies you have. Strange I find it. Hard for the eyes it is. Yes.